# Rewrite Rule. Remove everything Before double slash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Im I need of some help with rewrites. Ive search through posts for a simple solution, but just cant crack it.

I have a lot of urls which are incorrect. I need to rewrite a number of urls where everything before the double slash can go.

current url
http://www.website.com.au/category/subcategory//product-name-here.html

required url
http://www.website.com.au//product-name-here.html

If someone could please provide an example I would really appreciate it

brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
location ~ ^/category/subcategory {
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1;
  }
```